# Why is the normal vector used in this context to find the angle between two lines?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be the focis $(\epsilon p, 0)$, $(-\epsilon p, 0)$ of an ellipse $(p\cos(t), q\sin(t))$, where $\epsilon = \sqrt{1 - (q^2/p^2)}$. Then the tangent vector to the ellipse is given by $\gamma'(t) = (-p\sin(t), q\cos(t))$. Let $x$ be any point on the ellipse. We'd like to show that the angle between the line joining $f_1$ and $x$ and the tangent to the ellipse at $x$ is equal to the angle between the line joining $f_2$ and $x$ and the said tangent at $x$.

My source claims that we only need to show that $\frac{(p - f_1)\cdot n}{||p - f_1||} = \frac{(p - f_2)\cdot n}{||p - f_2||}$, where $n = (q\cos(t), p\sin(t))$ is the normal vector to the tangent at $x$. What I don't understand is that why are we using the normal vector to the tangent, when the tangent vector with which we ought to find the angle between vectors $a_i = p - f_i, i \in \{1, 2\}$?

Comment: Draw a sketch of the situation you have, and you'll see why this is so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Please see the diagram. Use the fact that the normal vector at any point on ellipse is perpendicular to the tangent line at that point. So if the normal vector bisects $ \angle f_1Pf_2$, $f_1P$ and $f_2P$ will make equal angles with the tangent line.

Comment: I seem to be a bit rusty with classical geometry. Why is it true that if the normal vector (or any line for that matter) bisects the said angle, then $f_1P$ and $f_2P$ will make equal angles with the tangent line?

Comment: As the angle between $f_1P$ and normal line is $\alpha$, the angle between $f_1P$ and tangent line is $90-\alpha$, right? Same for $f_2P$.